# NSPredicate that filters on the current time

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to create a `NSPredicate` (for use with Core Data in a `NSFetchRequest`, in a `NSFetchedresultsController`) that filters records based on the current time.

**NOT** the time when the predicate was created:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(criticalDate < %@)", [NSDate date]]`

But the time when the predicate is evaluated, as I would like to avoid updating the fetchedResultsController with new fetchRequests all the time. What I am looking for (but cannot find on my own) is something like this:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(criticalDate < ????)"]`

It is for the iPhone, which means that `now()` is not supported, so I guess whatever the solution is it will be sort of a hack.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry but `[NSDate date]` get the current date. So, what do you mean with *NOT the time when the predicated was created*?

Comment: @Flex_Addicted he means the time when the predicate is evaluated, not when it is created.

Comment: Yes, the time when it is evaluated. I am looking into doing a predicateWithBlock - but not getting the results I want, yet..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"criticalDate < now()"];
```

Comment: That will not work i iOS. At least I cannot make it work, and the [NSExpression Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:) says that `now()`will only work for OS X 10.5+

Comment: Why, you are absolutely right! Thank you for clearing that up. Much better/cleaner than the `predicateWithBlock:` kludge I concocted. Thank You, sir, and +1 to you.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that Core Data doesn't support the `now()` function. If you try to use it in a fetch, it'll throw with `Unsupported function expression now()`

Comment: @MikeAbdullah actually, IIRC support for the `now()` function has been added in iOS 8.

Comment: Ah, now that is interesting to know. I tested this with iOS 7.1

Comment: Any way I can get today's midnight time ? something like (midnight(now))

Answer (score 0):

If you create the predicate right before the fetch, the difference between the time the predicate is created and the time the fetch is executed can be at most a millisecond.

I cannot imaging a use scenario where this would be of any importance. Please explain.

However if that time difference is really too much for you, I suggest the following solution. Run a couple of tests to figure out what the most likely time difference is. Then, when you create your predicate, add the time difference into the future. Thus:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"criticalDate < %@", 
   [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:0.001]];
```

I guess this problem is sort of academic... :-)

Comment: The predicate (of which this time comparison is a part) is generated by a separate part of the application and handed to the view-controller. There are several timestamps in the model and the predicate-generating code picks the one it wants to have compared to now(), thus the predicate can be generated "some time" before it is used by the view-controller.

Comment: Then simply keep a timestamp when exactly the predicate is created and adjust it accordingly when you fetch.